# Capitalization of phrase from list

Tags: python, capitalization

I got two files 1) paragaph.txt and list.txt. I want a program to run through list.txt line by line and match it against phrases in paragraph.txt, if matches capitalize found matches in paragraph.txt.

Paragraph.txt

On the Insert tab, the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document. You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers, footers, lists, cover pages, and other document building blocks. When you create pictures, charts, or diagrams, they also coordinate with your current document look.
.

**list.txt -  List content is listed below:(but there are no bullet point in list.txt file, just
phrases one below the another)**

- Pictures, Charts, or Diagrams
- Building Blocks

Expected output

On the Insert tab, the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document. You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers, footers, lists, cover pages, and other document Building Blocks. When you create Pictures, Charts, or Diagrams, they also coordinate with your current document look.

**My understanding of the problem:**

If both contains data as listed items than the code below yields a result that could be title cased and returned to the paragraph. 
Can this approach be extended to paragraph? Should i have to use nltk n-gram model to coin two words phrases and 3 words phrase?

```
with open("paragraph.txt") as f, open("list.txt") as g:
  l=f.readlines()
  l1=g.readlines()
  print list(set(l)&set(l1))
```

**Some improvement:**
Now able to identify phrase and match it against paragraph and return matches as capitalized.

```
capitalized_phrases = open("list.txt").readlines()
words = open("paragraph.txt").read()

for phrase in capitalized_phrases:
    all_words_found = False
    capitalized_phrases = phrase.lower().split(" ")
    for word in capitalized_phrases:
        if word  in words:
            all_words_found = True
            break

    if all_words_found:
       print phrase.title()
```

So, now the key is to replace the found matches (titlecased) in place of original content within the paragraph. any help?

Comment: elaborate your actual `list.txt` content, has it `List item` as header line(as you have shown in the question)?

Comment: Please see bold list.txt